# How can I disable bold styling of headings in Markdown?

Tags: markdown

If you make a header, like this:

```markdown
# Test
```

You get something like this:

> ## Test

It's in bold.

How do I remove the boldness?

Comment: What do you mean *"in Markdown"*? Markdown just converts it to a `h1`, formatting beyond that is up to whatever's rendering it.

Comment: @jonrsharpe basically, I want an h1 tag that's forced to be lightweight/unbold/whatever its called from within markdown.

Comment: Well, why? What are you trying to achieve? You can fall back to HTML I suppose `<h1 style="font-weight: normal">Test</h1>`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe because the program I am using (https://homebrewery.naturalcrit.com/) uses markdown.

Comment: But it can also handle some HTML, which I just tested, and that works!

Comment: Yes, Markdown is basically a superset of HTML.

Answer (score 0):

It will depend on whatever renderer application you are using, and may also depend on what Markdown specification that renderer application supports. Usually those applications have some configuration mechanism, such as CSS. For example [VS Code's builtin Markdown extension](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/tree/main/extensions/markdown-language-features) has the `markdown.styles` setting. In the CSS cases, the details of what selectors (classnames) will be available for writing style rules will depend on the application. The CSS property of interest would probably be [`font-weight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-weight). You may also be able to write the CSS inline in the markup- [CommonMark supports the `<style>` tag](https://spec.commonmark.org/0.30/#html-blocks) (though it's up to the rendering application what CSS properties they want to support- some are quite conservative, and because of the whole- the rendering application chooses what classnames it uses- thing, you'll have some work to do if you want to write something fairly portable). If the rendering is done by some browser application that doesn't have any builting configuration support, you can probably write a userstyle (basically a CSS userscript) to do local customization.

Answer (score -1):

**A HEADER** IS JUST TEXT **WITH BIGGER FONT SIZE**

And markdown is just like another HTML or XML with TAGS so use *font* TAG and *size* attribute like this:

`<font size="10">**A HEADER** IS JUST TEXT **WITH BIGGER FONT SIZE**</font>`

Think about it ;)

Comment: won't someone _please_ think of the <strike>children</strike> _semantics_!? Also,  I don't think `<font>` is [standard CommonMark](https://spec.commonmark.org/0.30/#html-blocks). It might happen to be supported by specific renderer applications.